# Running Maven project by adding dependency

Tags: maven, nlp, dependencies

I am trying to run this DDR (Deep Dependency Representation) conversion tool from Emory NLP: https://github.com/elitcloud/elit-java/tree/master/elit-ddr

I have created a new Maven project in a new directory called depConverter and added the specified dependency from the website into the pom.xml file in DepConverter. This pom.xml file was the one built from automatically creating a new, default Maven project. I think I am missing something from this pom.xml file to properly run the DDR tool, as when I run the specified command line command `java cloud.elit.ddr.bin.DDRConvert -i relcl.parse -oe tsv` in depConverter, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class cloud.elit.ddr.bin.DDRConvert
```

I am not totally clear on how Maven will load this class. Do I have to create a java file to run this tool?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the question is about running from the command line:

DDR library is not in the classpath when you're trying to run from command line. That's why JVM cannot load the main class that is expected to be found in this library.

So you can try to run:

```
java -classpath <PATH_TO_DDR_JAR> cloud.elit.ddr.bin.DDRConvert -i relcl.parse -oe tsv
```

This is the easiest way.
The jar is expected to be found in the local maven repository (~/.m2/repository by default).

Maven is a build tool in a nutshell and it doesn't run anything inside your artifact/ one of the dependencies like in your case.

Alternatively, if you want to "use" the information provided in pom (like a dependency graph), you still can run `mvn exec:exec` / `mvn exec:java` plugin and supply the relevant parameters to run the class of your choice.

You can find more information about exec plugin [here](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html).

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the classpath! The new issue I'm running into is with the input file syntax. If I don't specify <PATH_TO_INPUT FILE> right after the -i option, I get the error message: Error: `Could not find or load main class relcl.parse`

Comment: I've tried using the angle brackets to specify the path: `java -classpath </Users/Daniel/Desktop/PS_to_Dep/depConverter/elit-java-master/elit-ddr/src/main/java/cloud/elit/ddr/bin/> cloud.elit.ddr.bin.DDRConvert -i </Users/Daniel/Desktop/PS_to_Dep/depConverter/elit-java-master/elit-ddr/src/test/resources/conversion/english/> relcl.parse -oe tsv` but then I get `Unrecognized option: -oe
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.` I've even put the relcl.parse file directly into depConverter, but it still "can't find main class".

Comment: You dont need square brackets it was just a placeholder. BTW you said you use maven. Do you actually have any java code in your own module or you used maven just to download a DDR jar?

Comment: I used Maven to download a DDR jar. I seem to have found a solution by running mvn clean install and then specifying a classpath from there. This was the final command I ended up using (a friend helped me figure out the classpath) but to be honest i'm not really sure why it works. `java -cp elit-ddr/target/elit-ddr-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar cloud.elit.ddr.bin.DDRConvert -d directory/with/parse/files`

Comment: In any case, I wasn't able to actually use the commands listed in the original website. Those still gave me errors.

Comment: That's what I really meant (cp and classpath are the same): java -cp elit-ddr/target/elit-ddr-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar cloud.elit.ddr.bin.DDRConvert -d directory/with/parse/files If you just download jar, then basically you don't need maven here at all, you need only to download the "already built" version of jar and run the command. Maven is required if you actually want to be build your own stuff (with possible dependencies on other thirdparties). Now If you have some concrete errors that DDR prints, you can ask another question with a concrete error statement.